# Outlook alter html code when converting from msg

Tags: html, css, templates, outlook, msg

What i did:

1. created an html template:

   ```
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
   <table><tbody>
   <tr>
   <td><table><tbody>
   <tr><td><h3>title 1</h3></td><td><h4 id="title_1">AAA</h4></td></tr>
   <tr><td><h3>title 2</h3></td><td><h4 id="title_2">BBB</h4></td></tr>
   <tr><td><h3>title 3</h3></td><td><h4 id="title_3">CCC</h4></td></tr>
   <tr><td><h3>title 4</h3></td><td><h4 id="title_4">DDD</h4></td></tr>
   <tr><td><h3>title 5</h3></td><td><h4 id="title_5">EEE</h4></td></tr>
   </td></tbody></table>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>Well</td></tr>
   </tbody></table>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. I saved it as a template in outlook 2010 (in IE File->Send page by email. than in Outlook: save. save as template)
3. I used the template, and sent it to my self.
4. I saved the msg file as an html file.
5. i looked at the source code of the new html file and it is completley different!

here is the code i got:

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 14">
<base href="file:///C:\Users\***\Desktop\Templates\temp2.html">
<link rel=File-List
href="file:///C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\Test2_files\filelist.xml">
<link rel=Edit-Time-Data
href="file:///C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\Test2_files\editdata.mso">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 ...
</xml><![endif]-->
<link rel=themeData
href="file:///C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\Test2_files\themedata.thmx">
<link rel=colorSchemeMapping
href="file:///C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\Test2_files\colorschememapping.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
  <w:TrackMoves/>
  <w:TrackFormatting/>
  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
  <w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>HE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
   <w:DoNotExpandShiftReturn/>
   <w:BreakWrappedTables/>
   <w:SplitPgBreakAndParaMark/>
   <w:EnableOpenTypeKerning/>
  </w:Compatibility>
  <w:BrowserLevel>MicrosoftInternetExplorer4</w:BrowserLevel>
  <m:mathPr>
   <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"/>
   <m:brkBin m:val="before"/>
   <m:brkBinSub m:val="&#45;-"/>
   <m:smallFrac m:val="off"/>
   <m:dispDef/>
   <m:lMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:rMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:defJc m:val="centerGroup"/>
   <m:wrapIndent m:val="1440"/>
   <m:intLim m:val="subSup"/>
   <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"/>
  </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="true"
  DefSemiHidden="true" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="267">
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="0" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Normal"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="heading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="heading 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="heading 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="35" QFormat="true" Name="caption"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="10" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Title"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" Name="Default Paragraph Font"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="11" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtitle"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="22" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Strong"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="20" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="59" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Table Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Placeholder Text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="No Spacing"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Revision"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="34" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="List Paragraph"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="29" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Quote"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="30" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Quote"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="19" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtle Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="21" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="31" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtle Reference"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="32" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Reference"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="33" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Book Title"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="37" Name="Bibliography"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" QFormat="true" Name="TOC Heading"/>
 </w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]-->
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Cambria;
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
    mso-font-alt:"Calisto MT";
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:roman;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-536870145 1073743103 0 0 415 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
    mso-font-alt:"Japanese Gothic";
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-536870145 1073786111 1 0 415 0;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
h3
    {mso-style-priority:9;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-link:"Heading 3 Char";
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    mso-outline-level:3;
    font-size:13.5pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
h4
    {mso-style-priority:9;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-link:"Heading 4 Char";
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    mso-outline-level:4;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-underline:single;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-underline:single;}
span.Heading3Char
    {mso-style-name:"Heading 3 Char";
    mso-style-priority:9;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-locked:yes;
    mso-style-link:"Heading 3";
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:Cambria;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Cambria;
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-weight:bold;}
span.Heading4Char
    {mso-style-name:"Heading 4 Char";
    mso-style-priority:9;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-locked:yes;
    mso-style-link:"Heading 4";
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:Cambria;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Cambria;
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;}
span.EmailStyle19
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-hansi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    mso-default-props:yes;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    mso-ansi-font-size:10.0pt;
    mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;
    mso-header-margin:.5in;
    mso-footer-margin:.5in;
    mso-paper-source:0;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
    mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
    mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
    mso-para-margin:0in;
    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple style='tab-interval:.5in'>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:120.0pt;text-indent:-120.0pt;tab-stops:
120.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><b><span
style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;
color:black'>From:<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>                              </span></span></b><span
style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;
color:black'>***<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:120.0pt;text-indent:-120.0pt;tab-stops:
120.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><b><span
style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;
color:black'>Sent:<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>                               </span></span></b><span
style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;
color:black'>Tuesday, September 02, 2014 1:33 PM<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:120.0pt;text-indent:-120.0pt;tab-stops:
120.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><b><span
style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;
color:black'>To:<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>                                   </span></span></b><span
style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;
color:black'>***<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:120.0pt;text-indent:-120.0pt;tab-stops:
120.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><b><span
style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;
color:black'>Subject:<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>                          </span></span></b><span
style='font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;
color:black'>Test2<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellpadding=0 style='mso-cellspacing:1.5pt;
 mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
 <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
  <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
  <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellpadding=0 style='mso-cellspacing:
   1.5pt;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
   <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h3><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>title 1<o:p></o:p></span></h3>
    </td>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h4 id="title_1"><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>AAA<o:p></o:p></span></h4>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h3><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>title 2<o:p></o:p></span></h3>
    </td>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h4 id="title_2"><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>hhhhhh<o:p></o:p></span></h4>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2'>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h3><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>title 3<o:p></o:p></span></h3>
    </td>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h4 id="title_3"><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>CCC<o:p></o:p></span></h4>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:3'>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h3><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>title 4<o:p></o:p></span></h3>
    </td>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h4 id="title_4"><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>DDdhgdfgD<o:p></o:p></span></h4>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:4;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h3><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>title 5<o:p></o:p></span></h3>
    </td>
    <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
    <h4 id="title_5"><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>EEE<o:p></o:p></span></h4>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
  <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
  <p class=MsoNormal>Well</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Why is it happening and how can i prevent it?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft products have their own style of writing HTML.

Comment: But now it makes the whole html unreadable! Can i prevent it? Maybe by using an other tool to convert the msg to html?

Comment: No you can't. One day you're still using Microsoft's products, you can't avoid these.